# Copy commands from console

Tags: r

I use R 3.0.3 in Windows.

How do I copy commands to notepad which I have typed in R console without `'>'` sign and the output?

The usual method of copy-paste don't work because it will copy the output as well as the `'>'` sign.

Comment: How about copying from the command history? For example, `history(max.show==2000)`. History is displayed without the leading prompt sign (">").

Comment: If you get RStudio you can open the history panel and copy what you want from there. Or even better save everything as a .R script (Also very convenient in RStudio).

Comment: Make that `history(max.show=2000)` in my comment above.

Comment: Similar to the `history()` command @JTT mentions: In the console, you can click on "File", then "Save History". This will save the commands you typed in the current session to an `.Rhistory` file, which is a plain text file. You can then copy & paste whatever you need.

Comment: I don't type into R, I just write everything in the script and submit it to R via shortcut. Keeps production time down, down.

Comment: @JTT it's '=' not '=='. Nice answer by the way!

Comment: @RomanLuštrik what do you mean via shortcut?

Comment: I use IDE(s) that have special shortcuts for sending lines or blocks of code from the script to R. I use Eclipse+StatET plugin and RStudio. Another option is ESS.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but what you can do is `Paste commands only` in GUI (Rgui.exe on Windows). That way, comments are stripped and `>` removed.